# How to limit a textarea input to alphanumeric and erase others with javascript

Tags: javascript, textarea

I found this - but it is not working.

Maybe it needs more knowledge ...

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('textarea').keyup(function(){
        var input_val = $(this).val();
        var inputRGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/;
        var inputResult = inputRGEX.test(input_val);
        if(!(inputResult))
        {     
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what you mean "it's not working"? van you please post the HTML code?

Comment: My problem is a lack of coding competence.

I have a form with a textarea field.
In this field the user should only be able to put characters and numbers, no special characters ...

Comment: @IsabelTenbrink take a look at "pattern" attribute here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_pattern.asp. Applying it to the textarea input, a user will be able to enter only characters that are allowed by the specified Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing the regex against the entire value and replacing it, you can test it against the character for every key stroke. If the character doesn't match the patter you return false & hence it won't be written to the text area.

```js
$(function() {
  // Taking event as an argument in the callback & also changed keyup to keydown
  $('textarea').keydown(function(e) {
    // e.key is the current character the user tried to input
    console.log(e.key);
    
    if(!/^[A-Za-z0-9? ,_-]+$/.test(e.key))
      // Returning false will not write it to the textarea
      return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```